# Node.js: Error "Exported external package typings file"

Tags: node.js, module, typescript, gulp

In short:

- Node.js-project, changing from javascript to typescript
- npm install mongoose
- typings install mongoose --save --ambient

If I do 'import mongoose = require("mongoose");' and enter execute gulp I get:

```
server/categories/categories.model.ts(1,29): error TS2656: 
Exported external package typings file
'/vagrant/node_modules/mongoose/index.ts' is not a module.
Please contact the package author to update the package definition.
```

In Visual Studio Code the message is the same if I hover, but on the other side it uses the type-definition, as I can resolve my mongoose-Module normally. I  don't understand why it thinks that index.ts should be a type-definition.

I'm not quite sure if this information is sufficient, so please let me know if not.

thanks in advance.

Some excerpts:

- gulpfile.js

  ```
  var tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");

  gulp.task("build", function() {
  return gulp.src([
          "server/**/**.ts",
          "typings/main.d.ts"            
      ])
      .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
      .js.pipe(gulp.dest("server/"));
  });
  ```
- tsconfig.json

  ```
       "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "isolatedModules": false,
  "jsx": "react",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "removeComments": true,
  "noLib": false,
  "preserveConstEnums": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
   "filesGlob": [
   "**/*.ts",
   "**/*.tsx",
   "!node_modules/**",
   "!typings/browser/**"
   ]
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the problem was, but finally a delete of node_modules and npm install solved the problems. Perhaps I destroyed some files within node_modules while experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

> is not a module.

Just ran the following quick test and it worked fine. Make sure you are using the latest `typings` / `typescript`.

## Update typings

`npm i typings -g`

## Proof I tested

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't think this is the problem (typings was fresh installed at a version of 0.7.12).

Comment: I did:
mkdir mongotest
cd mongotest
node int (with default)
npm install node mongoose --save
typings install node mongoose --save --ambient
took tsconfig.json from above and your test.ts
with tsc -p ./tsconfig.json, I'm getting following (and many more same sounding errors):
typings/main/ambient/mocha/index.d.ts(25,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'bail'

I'm seeing that typings/main/ambient and typings/browser/ambient is used, I assumed "filesGlob" should help here ...

Comment: But the original error I don't see here, So my questions: 

- Why does filesGlob not work as expected
- Another idea what could lead to index.ts in mongoose is identified as a module? (As said not seen on this small test)